# RemoteApp window display issue on reconnect

Tags: remoteapp

I am running windows server 2019 datacenter, with a basic RemoteApp install. When I initially connect to a session, everything displays as expected. When I disconnect and then reconnect to the session, most of my windows get a thick blue border and some dark mode elements do not display correctly.

Initial connect:
[explorer on initial connection to remoteapp session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsaxL.png)
Reconnect:
[explorer on reconnection to session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCKZQ.png)

I tried to change settings related to remotefx in gpedit, as well as regedit. Nothing I tried seemed to make any difference.

Comment: It looks like the issue is related to windows themes. If I go to settings -> personalization -> themes and select the Windows theme, it fixes it until I reconnect again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set "Themes" service in services.msc to manual or disabled. The issue was that for some reason it was setting windows to use aerolite theme instead of just aero